# Is there a way to show more details about a Relational Field in Django REST Framework JSON API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, json-api

I'm trying to use the Django REST Framework JSON API and was wondering if there is a way to serialize Relations (ForeignKey and all) with a bit more detail compared to :

```
"post": {
          "type": "Post",
          "id": 1
        }
```

I was thinking of something along the lines of :

```
"post": {
          "type": "Post",
          "id": 1,
          "name": "First Post"
          "tag": "Development"
        }
```

Comment: Can you show your model and serializer?

Comment: @Arty Please go through this first, [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then add relevant information to your question/problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
       model = Album
       fields = ('album_name', 'artist', 'tracks')
```

for relations look here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/